# super() in nested classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

What is going on here?

```
class foo:
    def bogh(self):
        return "foobar"
    class bar:
        def gugh(self):
            return super().bogh()
        
foofoo = foo.bar()
print(foofoo.gugh()) # throws AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'bogh'
```

It seems like it should work, right? Doesn't the super() object return a proxy object containing the parent class's functions and attributes? But it doesn't have them. I ran a dir() on the super() class, and it gave me this:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__']
```

No trace of the bogh() function.

However, I can get it to work if I de-"nest" the functions, like this:

```
class foo:
    def bogh(self):
        return "foobar"
    
class bar(foo):
    def gugh(self):
        return super().bogh()
        
foofoo = bar()
print(foofoo.gugh()) # prints "foobar"
```

Why doesn't it work if the classes are "nested"? And is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: super() only works for inherited classes, not for nested classes.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because *nesting* classes is different than *inheriting* classes.

If `bar` would *inherit* from `foo`, then indeed `super()` would work as intended.

But *nesting* has nothing to do with inheritance, and therefore class `bar` does not gain access to any of the methods of `foo`.

The point of nesting is merely to control visibility. So in your code example, the nesting makes the strong case that class `bar` really doesn't make any sense outside of class `foo` and therefore doesn't deserve to be its own top-level class.

So again, summary: Nesting does *not* imply inheritance and therefore doesn't establish a parent-child relationship between classes.

Btw: In your de-nested example, there's no need to actually call `super()`. The whole point of inheritance is to enable *automated* message delegation. This code works just as well:

```py
class foo:
    def bogh(self):
        return "foobar"
    
class bar(foo):
    def gugh(self):
        return self.bogh()    # No need for super
        
foofoo = bar()
print(foofoo.gugh()) # prints "foobar"
```